# Delay "unhover" action

Tags: css, hover, delay

```css
#login-panel-ghost {
  display: none;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
.top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<span class="top-menu-login">Login
  <div id="login-panel-ghost">
    <h2>Log in!</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
    </form>
  </div>
</span>
```

Now, let me explain what I would like to accomplish: I've a `span` `.top-menu-login` which will be displayed as a phrase, in this case "Login". Furthermore, the `div` `#login-panel-ghost` is originally hidden, but when the mouse passes over "Login" the `div` should appear.

I managed to do that, the problem is that I would like to delay the element disappearing after the mouse unhovers the "Login"!

I've tried this code so far, that I found on Stack Overflow, but I think the fact that the hover changes another `div` is causing trouble.

P.S. I know it should be easy with JavaScript, but I'd like to try without it!

Comment: First of all, you should not wrap a `div` inside a `span`: it's not intended to be a container. Then, you should use something like `out` event in jQuery to handle the disappearing of your "login box".

Comment: Main takeaway from this is that the property Display cannot be animated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right lines using `transition-delay: 2s;`, however, there are a couple of factors that mean this won't work:

- You cannot animate `display`, it is either there (`display: block;`) or not (`display: none;`)
- You are not specifying a `transition` so there is nothing for `transition-delay: 2s;` to effect

To make this work using CSS you can do the following:

- Add `height: 0;` to `#login-panel-ghost` to effectively hide the element
- Add `height: 180px;` to `.top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost` to effectively show the element
- Transition on the `height` changing it from `0` to `180px` by adding `transition: height 0s;` to `#login-panel-ghost`
- Add `overflow: hidden;` to allow the content that exceeds the boundries of `#login-panel-ghost` to be hidden
- Add `transition-delay: 2s;` to `#login-panel-ghost` to delay the transition when `.top-menu-login` is not hovered over
- Add `transition-delay: 0s;` to `#.top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost` to ensure there is no delay when the user hovers over the element

```css
#login-panel-ghost {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
.top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost {
  height: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu-login">Login
  <div id="login-panel-ghost">
    <h2>Log in!</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Key point here is Display cannot be animated.

Answer (score 2):

`transition` property not work on `display` instead use `opacity` like:

```css
#login-panel-ghost {
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 2s, opacity 2s;
}

.top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost {
     visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<span class="top-menu-login">Login
    <div id="login-panel-ghost">
        <h2>Log in!</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </form>
    </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.top-menu-login").on("mouseover", function(){
            $("#login-panel-ghost").show();
        });
        $("div.top-menu-login").on("mouseout", function(){
            $("#login-panel-ghost").hide({duration:2000});
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    #login-panel-ghost {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-menu-login:hover #login-panel-ghost {
        position: fixed;
        width: 250px;
        height: 180px;
    }
</style>
<div class="top-menu-login">Login
    <div id="login-panel-ghost">
        <h2>Log in!</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing you have to do is to customize the `hide` object to choose effect, ... you want.

You can check this parameters here : http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("element").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#color');
    }, function(){
        // change to any color that was previously used.
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#color');
    });
});
```

It's easier with jQuery. Good luck!